# Logic OR in a DSL

Tags: drools, dsl, rules

I have a question around how to do an or in a DSLR, I have this rule:

```
rule "Test"
    when
        There is AThing
        - with attribute1 is equal to something1
        - attribute2 is higher than or equal to somethingelse1

        There is AThing
        - with attribute1  is equal to something2
        - attribute2 is higher than or equal to somethingelse2
    then
        something is valid
end
```

that rewrites to a dlr like:

```
rule "Test"
    when
        AThing(attribute1 ==  something1, attribute2  >=  somethingelse1)
        AThing(attribute1 ==  something2, attribute2  >= somethingelse2)
    then
        something is valid
end
```

what's the best way to put the 2 condition into an OR in the DSLR? I would like to write something like:

```
rule "Test"
    when
        (There is AThing
        - with attribute1 is equal to something1
        - attribute2 is higher than or equal to somethingelse1)
        or
        (There is AThing
        - with attribute1  is equal to something2
        - attribute2 is higher than or equal to somethingelse2)
    then
        something is valid
end
```

but the Drools compiler is complaining, I tried many combinations of parenthesis.

In this case I could write 2 separate rules, but in reality they are part of a most complex rule I would like to avoid to repeat two big rules just for an or.

Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to write this as two rules - which will happen anyway.

The syntax requires you to write an infix or on the LHS as

```
when
( Type(...)
or
  Type(...) )
then
```

and the prefix or as

```
when
(or Type(...)
    Type(...))
then
```

neither of which is easy to achieve using a DSL. The best you can do is to write the parentheses and the or on a line prefixed with a greater sign (`>`) which will simply pass the remainder through to the DRL output.

```
when
> (
  Type(...)
> or
  Type(...)
> )
```

But a condition like your example can also be combined like this:

```
when
    AThing(attribute1 == something1 && attribute2 >=  somethingelse1
           ||
           attribute1 == something2 && attribute2 >= somethingelse2)
then
```

but this will be difficult to achieve using a DSL. (Which, as I wrote in another corner of SO,...)

Comment: don't be so negative!! :) Thank you anyway, will try this!